# Knockout.JS: 'delete' request

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

Why doesn't it work to delete the element from the table and refresh the page ?
I got a web api with a delete method implemented that works just fine on Postman.
I have no idea what am I doing wrong. I've implemented the get using jquery and knockout.

```html
<table data-bind="foreach: students">
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Nume</th>
            <th>Prenume</th>
            <th>Data</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="id_" size="1"  data-bind="value: StudId" disabled="disabled"></td>
            <td><input type="text" size="60" data-bind="value: Nume" disabled="disabled"></td>
            <td><input type="text" size="60" data-bind="value: Prenume" disabled="disabled"></td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" size="15" data-bind="value: Data" disabled="disabled">
                <input type="button" value="Sterge" class="button button1" id="sterge" />
                <input type="button" class="button button2" value="Editeaza" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br /><br />
</div>
```

```js
var uri = 'api/student'

function studentModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.students = ko.observableArray([]);

    $.getJSON(uri, function (data) {
        self.students(data);
    })
}
ko.applyBindings(new studentModel());

$(function () {
    $('#sterge').click(function () {
        var id = $('#id_').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'DELETE',
            url: uri + '/' + id,
            success: function (result) {
                alert('Student sters cu succes! ');
                location.reload();
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert('Stergere esuata! ');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Why don't you use knockout click binding since you are using it ? Remember 'id' is a unique selector in document.

Comment: @Matt.kaaj How can I do it ? Im a beginner in all this ..

Comment: Check out what I posted for delete event binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things going wrong here:

1. At the time you're attaching event listeners, the elements they need to be attached to do not yet exist.
2. You're using `id` attributes inside a `foreach` binding: this will result in duplicate ids.

When knockout applies its bindings, the `students` observable array is still empty. Its items are loaded via the API.

I'd suggest using the `click` binding to attach your delete method. You should also remove the `id` attributes.

```js
var testData = [
  { StudId: 1, Nume: "Jane", Prenume: "Deer", Data: 14 },
  { StudId: 2, Nume: "John", Prenume: "Doe", Data: 10 }
];



var uri = 'api/student';

var StudentsViewModel = function() {
  this.students = ko.observableArray();

  this.loadStudents();
};

StudentsViewModel.prototype.loadStudents = function() {
  var self = this;
  $.getJSON(uri, function(data) {
    self.students(data);
  });
};

StudentsViewModel.prototype.deleteStudent = function(id) {
  console.log("Post delete for id: " + id);
  $.ajax({
    type: 'DELETE',
    url: uri + '/' + id,
    success: function(result) {
      alert('Student sters cu succes! ');
    },
    error: function(error) {
      alert('Stergere esuata! ');
    }
  });
  
  
};

// Mock jquery ajax stuff
var $ = {
  getJSON: function(uri, cb) {
    setTimeout(cb.bind(null, testData), 750);
  },
  ajax: function() {}
};

// Apply bindings
ko.applyBindings(new StudentsViewModel());
```

```css
input { width: 50px }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table >
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Nume</th>
    <th>Prenume</th>
    <th>Data</th>
  </tr>
  <!-- ko foreach: students -->
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input data-bind="value: StudId" type="text" size="1" disabled="disabled">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input data-bind="value: Nume" type="text" size="60" disabled="disabled">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input data-bind="value: Prenume" type="text" size="60" disabled="disabled">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input data-bind="click: $parent.deleteStudent.bind($parent, $data.StudId)" type="button" value="Sterge" class="button button1"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <!-- /ko -->
</table>
<br />
<br />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I was really confused but I've understood now. Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a clean way to do what you want to do :https://jsfiddle.net/kyr6w2x3/23/

```
<table data-bind="foreach: students">
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Nume</th>
            <th>Prenume</th>
            <th>Data</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="id_" size="1"  data-bind="value: StudId" disabled="disabled"></td>
            <td><input type="text" size="60" data-bind="value: Nume" disabled="disabled"></td>
            <td><input type="text" size="60" data-bind="value: Prenume" disabled="disabled"></td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" size="15" data-bind="value: Data" disabled="disabled">
                <input type="button" value="Sterge" class="button button1" id="sterge" data-bind="click:$parent.deleteItem"/>
                <input type="button" class="button button2" value="Editeaza" data-bind="click:$parent.editItem"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

**JS:**

```
var uri = [{StudId:1,Nume: "Test",Prenume: "AAAAA",Data:"DATA1"},{StudId:2,Nume: "Test2",Prenume: "BBBB",Data:"DATA2"},{StudId:3,Nume: "Test3",Prenume: "CCCC",Data:"DATA3"}]

function mainModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.students = ko.observableArray([]);

    // Assuming you're getting your data here
    self.students($.map(uri, function (item) {
      return new studentModel(item);
    }));

    self.deleteItem = function (data){
    // here you send your ajax 
        console.log("Delete : Ready to send ajax for id: ",data.StudId());
        $.ajax({
              type: 'DELETE',
              url: uri + '/' + data.StudId(),
              success: function(result) {
                   ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.students(), function (item) {
                     if(item){
                       if(item.StudId() === data.StudId()){
                          self.students.remove(item);
                        }
                      }
                     }); 
              },
             error: function(error) {
                    alert('Stergere esuata! ');
              }
        });

   }

   self.editItem = function (data){
    // here you send your ajax 
     console.log("Edit :Ready to send ajax for id: ",data.StudId());
   }
}
function studentModel(data) {
    var self = this;
   self.StudId = ko.observable(data.StudId);
   self.Nume = ko.observable(data.Nume);
   self.Prenume = ko.observable(data.Prenume);
   self.Data = ko.observable(data.Data)
}
ko.applyBindings(new mainModel());
```

Comment: What am I doing wrong ? It doesnt seem to display anything.
I got this error in browser: jquery-3.0.0.js:531 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in api/student